# Separate texture in viewport

Tags: uv, 3d-view

Is there a way to assign a separate texture for specific 3D View? 
Like if I have some texture in material node, but want to see UV checker in viewport without changing material itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning separate materials to a view port is not possible ( as far I know )

**Alternative:**
With the Node Wrangler plugin you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on a node, and it will change it to that specific node. So you can just add an image texture to your node an swap between them.

[image]

See: http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/ ( Emission Viewer )